# deleting and updating a record in mysql using nodejs and express with ejs templating engine

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

Am just beginning my web dev journey and ran into a few problems. 
I am trying to delete and update any of the record in mysql using the following code:

```
    //deleting a record
Router.get('/delete', (req, res, next)=> {
  db.query('DELETE FROM student WHERE student_id = ?',req.body.student_id, (err,rs)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    else {
      res.redirect('showStudents');
    }
  });
});


//editing a record
Router.get('/edit',(req, res, next)=>{
  db.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE `student_id`=?',[req.body], (err,rs)=>{
    res.render('form',{Students: rs})
  });
});
Router.post('/edit',(req, res, next)=>{
  var params=[
    req.body,
    req.query.student_id
  ]
  db.query('UPDATE student SET? WHERE student_id =?',params, (err,rs)=>{
    if(!err)
    res.redirect('showStudents')
    else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

This is the arrangement of the code in ejs:

```
 <a href="/delete?student_id= <%= student.student_id %>" onClick=" return confirm ('Are you sure you?')">Delete</a>
<a href="/edit?student_id =<%= student.student_id %>">Edit</a>
```

running the delete code, I get this error below. With edit code, nothing changes.

{
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'DELETE FROM student WHERE student_id = ?'
}

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure if ths it the cause of the problem, but remove the space between the ejs variable and the "=" on delete. <a href="/delete?student_id=<%= student.student_id %>"

Comment: I tried removing the space, it's not working. But if I substitute the ? with a student_id value, it successfully deletes the record.

Comment: console.log your req.body inside the routes to see if the values are being send from the browser to your server

Comment: If you have the defined models maybe you should use the sequelize functions like update(), destroy(), findByPk()... https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html

Comment: console.log(req.body) returns { }.

Comment: hum..  since you´re sending the params through the url, I believe you need to get them with req.query Ex.: var student_id= req.query.student_id;

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's nice, glad to help, I will turn the comment into an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you´re sending your parameters through a query string in the url you need to access them with req.query Ex.: var student_id= req.query.student_id; 
(use req.body when the parameters are sent by form)